# Using remote: true from .js file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

This is almost an identical question as was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571985/rails-remote-true-equivalent, but no one answered.  I am hoping this doesn't mean that the question is impossible, though.

I have a page where a list of people can be dragged and dropped into bins.  An assignment in a join table is automatically generated when they are dropped.  I want the page to not re-load, though.  In ruby, I would do this using remote: true, but the re-direct here happens in my javascript file. I believe everything is set up correctly, if only I could put remote: true at the end of my window.location.pathname line in the .js file.

z_game_sessions.js

```
app.gameSession = {
  dragDrop: function () {
    $('.groups-students').sortable({
      tolerance:"pointer",
      revert: true
    });

    $('.draggables').draggable({
      connectToSortable: '.groups-students',
      revert: 'invalid',
      stop: function (e) {
        var id = e.target.id;
        var groupId = $(this).closest('ul').attr('id');

        if (groupId) {
          window.location.pathname = "game_sessions/add_player/" + groupId + "/" + id;
        }
      }
    });

  }
}
```

game_sessions_controller.rb

```
  def add_player
    @game_session = Group.find(params[:group_id]).game_session
    GroupAssignment.assign(params[:group_id], params[:student_id], @game_session.id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

add_player.js.erb

```
$("#new-group-form-container").html("<%= j(render partial: 'new_group_form', locals: {f: @game_session}) %>");
```

_new_group_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :groups do |ff| %>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-shadow--4dp group-assignment-forms" id="group<%= "#{ff.object.id}" %>">

      <h3>Group</h3>


      Password: <%= ff.object.password %>
      <%= ff.input :name, label: "Group Name", wrapper_html: { class: "mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label" }, input_html: { class: "mdl-textfield__input" }, label_html: { class: "mdl-textfield__label" } %>
      <%= ff.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, label: "Remove Group" %>

      <h4>Students</h4>

      <ul class="groups-students student-drag-area" id="<%= "#{ff.object.id}" %>">
        <% ff.object.students.each do |student| %>
          <li class="draggables" id="<%= student.id %>"><%= student.full_name %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>

  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it should be a POST request. Change your routes.

Second, make your controller return html and then just do an ajax request&assign that retuned html on success.

So instead of:

```
window.location.pathname = "game_sessions/add_player/" + groupId + "/" + id;
```

it should be something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "game_sessions/add_player/" + groupId + "/" + id,
  type: "POST",
  success: function(data) {
    $("#new-group-form-container").html(data)
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I got another error that means I got past the point where I was stuck!  I know how to fix this one, though :)